# Clearing default opening app

Tags: settings

Whenever i open .pdf file from file explorer it automatically opens with wps office but when wps office is unstalled it ask to choose app to open the pdf..How to make file explorer ask to choose program when i click on pdf file.I tried clearing default of all apps

Comment: Which version of Android are you using What is the file explorer? Can you be a little bit clear. If the file explorer is asking which app to open pdf files with. is it not the action you want

Comment: Its android 7.1.1 gionee inbuilt file explorer...yes file explorer ask that when i uninstalled the app (wps office) i want file explorer to ask when wps office is also installed

Comment: Yes, same problem here. I used WPS Office v12.2 build 332 armeabi-v7a on Redmi 6 Global, MIUI 10.4.4.0 Global Stable, and Android Pie. I'm using File Manager by Xiaomi. Still not fixed yet. Please help.

Comment: I suspect, it is caused by the File Manager, or WPS Office has been programmed, if it installed, then it will be the default opening app for supported file.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. My phone is using WPS office as its default to use pdfs. I cleared the defaults of all the apps but the problem persists. only if I uninstall WPS then the prompt appears to ask my choice of app. It's really frustrating since I like Adobe Acrobat for pdfs and keep WPS only for PPTs. Want to know if you could find a solution to this or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to clear the default action app:

- you already noticed it gets cleared when the corresponding app is deleted
- same applies if you install another app that could perform the same action
- there's a menu in settings where you can clear the default without (un)installing an app. Unfortunately, it's hard to find. Before Android 7 it had an own menu entry in settings. Since Android 7, you need to go to *Settings › Apps,* tap the app's entry, and will find if it's set as default. With that option you can also made it the default, or remove it from being default.

Comment: But there are no any default set in any of app..

Comment: I installed other file explorer z archiver it asked to choose between wps office and drive pdf viewer.and i ticked drive pdf viewer and ticked always.now from file explorer that pdf opens with wps office without any promt and with z archiver it opens with drive..now when i uninstalled and again installed z archiver it automatically opens pdf file with drive viewer..i am not getting any promt after agai installing

Comment: That's very strange. Have you tried installing another [PDF Viewer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf) (link goes to a list on my Android website)? If not, is WPS Office the only app registered for PDF? In that case, the system would chose it automatically, default or not, as it sees no alternative.

Comment: Yes i have many app..but no work it only opens with wps if it is installed . If not then it prompts. I think i have to compromise with that

Comment: I've got no idea what WPS does there, sorry. Have you checked in its settings (Settings › Apps › WPS Office) if there's something that lets you undo that? If there's not, I'm out of ideas.